# I cannot retrieve data in parse: Android Studio error

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
package com.example.database;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ParseObject gameScore;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
        gameScore.put("score", 1337);
        gameScore.put("playerName", "Player Name");
        gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
        gameScore.saveInBackground();


    }

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
    query.getInBackground("XXXXXXXX", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject gameScore, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // object will be your game score
            } else {
                // something went wrong
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am having trouble. I used the same tutorial using the Parse docs. However, it cannot resolve `getInBackground` and some other errors. Please help. By the way, Removing `ParseObject GameScore` doesn't work in this case.

```
10-17 15:48:18.334  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-17 15:48:18.494  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
10-17 15:48:18.494  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
10-17 15:48:18.494  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14146: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
10-17 15:48:18.494  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-17 15:48:18.494  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
10-17 15:48:18.494  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14150: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
10-17 15:48:18.494  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-17 15:48:18.544  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
10-17 15:48:18.544  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 435: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
10-17 15:48:18.544  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-17 15:48:18.544  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
10-17 15:48:18.544  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 457: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
10-17 15:48:18.544  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
10-17 15:48:18.834  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_MRVL.so
10-17 15:48:18.854  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_MRVL.so
10-17 15:48:18.905  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_MRVL.so
10-17 15:48:18.945  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database D/GC﹕ <tid=27958> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver rls_pxa988_KK44_GC13.25
10-17 15:48:18.985  27958-27958/com.alibdeir.database D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
```

It says on hover of getInBackground "Cannot resolve symbol getInBackground".
And over "e" it says cannot resolve symbol "e".
That is all

Comment: Can you print the exception and share it. It will be helpful to know the problem.

Comment: adb logcat , then share what exception you are getting.

Comment: @dex I edited the questoin